# Trouble using tkinter.button.place()

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use tkinter.button in the following method:

```
def _draw(self, canvas, options):
    p = self.anchor
    x,y = canvas.toScreen(p.x,p.y)
    frm = tk.Frame(canvas.master)
    frm.pack_propagate(0)
    frm.pack()
    self.button = tk.Button(frm,
                          height = self.height,
                          width = self.width,
                          text = self.label,
                          bg = self.fill,
                          fg = self.color,
                          font=self.font)
    self.button.place(self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width)
    #self.setFill(self.fill)
    self.button.focus_set()
    return canvas.create_window(x,y,window=frm)
```

I am currently getting the following error:

```
File "/Users/tmcdo13/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphics.py", line 913, in _draw
    self.button.place(self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width)
TypeError: place_configure() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

This confuses me because I am using button.place, not button.place_configure. Any ideas?

Comment: `button.place(...)` is just an alias for `button.place_configure`. That is why the error message mentions `place_configure`.

Comment: Oh, I see. But when I looked online I saw that button.place was able to run with more than 2 parameters, so why is an error occurring?

Comment: Where online did you see that? Maybe it's using a non-standard version of tkinter, or extending the class, or something.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_place.htm

Comment: That tutorial uses the code `B.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=100, width=100)`. Those arguments are keyword arguments; you are using positional arguments. You can't necessarily replace one with the other.

Comment: So I changed the parameters to keyword arguments and it runs, but when I use the method no button appears. It might be because I am trying to put it on top of a rectangle that I created earlier in my window. How can I put it on top of the rectangle. i tried to use draw(rect), but it doesn't run.                                                                                                        Note: the method shown above is in the button.py class that I appended onto the graphics.py class.

Comment: You are putting it in a frame that has a default size of 1x1. This is one of the disadvantages of `place`: it won't cause it's parent to grow or shrink to fit.

Comment: Is there a better option?

Comment: I changed the frame size and it appears, but the text doesn't appear and it seems inactive when I test it.